# Pasar el estado de un componente a otro componente en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, javascript-metodo

Hola necesito pasar el valor de la variable **GuaranteeAmount** a otro componente pero la manera en la que esta estipulado el componente no me es familiar quiero entender bien como funciona el proceso que realizaron y como se puede vincular este valor en otro componente

este es el primer componente que crea los valores a traves de una funcion y la verdad no comprendo como obtener estos valores de la funcion **getCommercialFields()**.

la ruta de este componente es **app** > **containers** > **project** > **fields.js**

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { getContactType, numberFormat } from 'containers/App/helpers';
    import ExUsers from 'components/ExForm/ExUsers';
    import ExConstructoras from 'components/ExForm/ExConstructoras';
    import ExInstitucionFinancieras from 'components/ExForm/ExInstitucionFinancieras';
    import IntlFormatNumber from 'components/IntlFormat/Number';
    
    import { userFullname } from '../Common/User/helper';
    
    const buildUsersField = (form, options = {}) => {
      const { tmp } = form.values;
      const {
        userProyectoType,
        label,
        roles,
        multiple = false,
        query = {},
        required = true,
      } = options;
      let selected = tmp.UsersProyecto[userProyectoType];
      if (!Array.isArray(selected) && selected) selected = [selected];
      return {
        ...options,
        label,
        required,
        name: `tmp.UsersProyecto[${userProyectoType}]`,
        multiple,
        value: selected,
        view: (selected || []).map(user => (
          <div
            className="text-nowrap"
            style={{ textOverflow: 'ellipsis' }}
            key={user.UserID}
          >
            {userFullname(user)}
          </div>
        )),
        query: {
          roles: roles || userProyectoType,
          selected,
          ...query,
        },
        Component: ExUsers,
      };
    };
    
    
    export const getCommercialFields = (form, { UsersInmobiliaria = [] } = {}) => {
      const {
        Arquitecto,
        Constructora,
        CotizacionDuration,
        GuaranteeAmount,
        DiscountMaxPercent,
        // EntregaInmediata,
        InstitucionFinanciera,
        IsSubsidy,
      } = form.values;
    
    
      return [
        /* Commercial Data */
        buildUsersField(form, {
          label: 'Asistente Comercial',
          userProyectoType: 'Asistente Comercial',
          required: false,
        }),
        buildUsersField(form, {
          label: 'Vendedor',
          userProyectoType: 'Vendedor',
          required: false,
        }),
        buildUsersField(form, {
          label: 'Representante Inmobiliaria',
          userProyectoType: 'Representante',
          multiple: true,
          query: {
            roles: [],
            mustIn: UsersInmobiliaria.filter(
              item => item.UserInmobiliariaType === 'Representante',
            ),
          },
          required: false,
        }),
        buildUsersField(form, {
          label: 'Aprobador Inmobiliaria',
          userProyectoType: 'Aprobador',
          multiple: true,
          query: {
            roles: [],
            mustIn: UsersInmobiliaria.filter(
              item => item.UserInmobiliariaType === 'Aprobador',
            ),
          },
          required: false,
        }),
        buildUsersField(form, {
          label: 'Autorizador Inmobiliaria',
          userProyectoType: 'Autorizador',
          multiple: true,
          query: {
            roles: [],
            mustIn: UsersInmobiliaria.filter(
              item => item.UserInmobiliariaType === 'Autorizador',
            ),
          },
          required: false,
        }),
        {
          label: 'Arquitecto',
          name: 'Arquitecto',
          view: Arquitecto || '',
          required: false,
        },
        buildUsersField(form, {
          label: 'Marketing',
          userProyectoType: 'Marketing',
          required: false,
        }),
        buildUsersField(form, {
          label: 'Legal',
          userProyectoType: 'Legal',
          required: false,
        }),
        buildUsersField(form, {
          label: 'Finanza',
          userProyectoType: 'Finanza',
          required: true,
          query: {
            roles: 'Finanza',
          },
        }),
        {
          label: 'Constructora',
          name: `ConstructoraID`,
          view: Constructora || '',
          Component: ExConstructoras,
          required: false,
        },
        {
          label: 'Duración Cotización',
          name: `CotizacionDuration`,
          view: `${CotizacionDuration || ''} Días`,
          type: 'number',
          required: false,
        },
        {
          label: 'Monto Reserva',
          name: `GuaranteeAmount`,
          view: <IntlFormatNumber prefix="$ " value={GuaranteeAmount} />,
          type: 'currency',
          min: 0,
          required: true,
        },
        {
          label: 'Institucion Financiera',
          name: `InstitucionFinancieraID`,
          view: InstitucionFinanciera || '',
          Component: ExInstitucionFinancieras,
          required: true,
        },
        {
          label: 'Descuento limite cotización',
          name: `DiscountMaxPercent`,
          view: `${DiscountMaxPercent || 100}`,
          maskOptions: { prefix: '%' },
          type: 'number',
          required: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
        },
        {
          label: 'Tiene Subsidio?',
          name: 'IsSubsidy',
          view: `${IsSubsidy || false}`,
          type: 'checkbox',
        },
      ];
    };
```

y este es el segundo componente llamado **Garantia** al que necesito pasar el valor de el input especificado anteriormente.

la ruta de este componente es **app** > **containers** > **Phases** > **Document** > **Garantia** > **index.js**

```
    /**
     *
     * Reservation Upload Form
     *
     */
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { Box, BoxContent, BoxHeader } from 'components/Box';
    import RadioGroup from 'components/ExForm/RadioGroup';
    import Button from 'components/Button';
    import {FormGroup, Label, Field as ExField} from 'components/ExForm';
    
    
    export function Garantia({
      isCollapse,
      entity,
      canUpload,
      onCancel,
      onGarantia,
      promesa,
    }) {
    
      return (
        <Box collapse isOpen={isCollapse}>
          <BoxHeader>
            <b>PAGO DE GARANTÍA</b>
          </BoxHeader>
          <BoxContent>
            <div className="row m-0 w-50 border-bottom pb-2 d-none">
              <RadioGroup
                className="d-flex align-items-center col-auto p-0"
                name="Pay"
                options={[
                  { label: 'Transferencia', value: 0 },
                  { label: 'Cheque', value: 1 },
                ]}
              />
            </div>
            <FormGroup className="col-12 col-md-6 d-flex my-3" >
              <Label className="w-50 ml-3 mr-5">Monto de Reserva Minimo</Label>
              <ExField
                className=" text-center w-50 ml-5"
                name="GuaranteeAmount.Amount"
                type="text"
                value={ '$ ' + 'Aca va el valor de GuaranteeAmount' }
                readOnly
                />
            </FormGroup>
          </BoxContent>
        </Box>
      );
    }
    
    Garantia.propTypes = {
      isCollapse: PropTypes.bool,
      canUpload: PropTypes.bool,
      entity: PropTypes.object,
      onGarantia: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.bool]),
      onCancel: PropTypes.func,
      promesa: PropTypes.bool,
    };
    
    export default Garantia;
```